# Decode bracket-encoded dictionary in query string

Tags: python, query-string

I have the following query string `'?attr[foo]=1&attr[bar]=2'`

Is there an easy way to decode that into a dictionary:`'{attr: {'foo':1,'bar':2}}'` using the existing libraries?

I know I can easily implement a decoder for this, just asking if there is a decoder that does this.

Comment: There is nothing in the standard library to handle this, because there is no standard that codifies that format.

Comment: Is there a standard way to encode a dictionary/hash on a URL? This is the default way Backbone does it, so I was wondering.

Comment: There are various competing 'standards', none of which ever made it to a standards body.

Comment: using sessions to pass dictionaries works pretty well imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
import urlparse

s = '?attr[foo]=1&attr[bar]=2'

def parse(s):
    d = {}
    for key, value in urlparse.parse_qs(s).items():
        match = re.match(r'(?P<key>[^\[]+)\[(?P<value>[^\]]+)\]', key)
        gd = match.groupdict()
        d.setdefault(gd['key'], {})[gd['value']] = value[0]
    return d

print(parse(s[1:]))
```

Prints:

```
{'attr': {'foo': '1', 'bar': '2'}}
```

Comment: The Regex is more protected than the one in my implementation. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Here is an alternative approach which answers your question in comments.

> Is there a standard way to encode a dictionary/hash on a URL?

You can use JSON, use `json.dumps()` and `urllib.parse.quote()` for the encoding:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
>>> quote(json.dumps({'attr': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}}))
'%7B%22attr%22%3A%20%7B%22foo%22%3A%201%2C%20%22bar%22%3A%202%7D%7D'
```

And `urllib.parse.unquote()` and `json.loads()` for the decoding:

```
>>> json.loads(unquote('%7B%22attr%22%3A%20%7B%22foo%22%3A%201%2C%20%22bar%22%3A%202%7D%7D'))
{'attr': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}}
```

Note that on Python 2.x the `urllib.parse` module does not exist, use `urllib2.quote()` and `urllib2.unquote()` instead.

The URL becomes a bit ugly because of the escaping but the encoding and decoding is trivial, so this is a good approach as long as you don't need people to be able to easily type or understand the encoded URL.

Comment: I would use this, but I need to be Backbone compatible, and don't want to override a bunch of `fetch`s.

Comment: It not helps to solve the question